# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.utils' after trying to install esm

Tags: python, pip

I was trying to install the Python Package esm ([Link to repo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/esm)). After installing the openfold option with:

```
pip install "fair-esm[esmfold]"
pip install 'dllogger @ git+https://github.com/NVIDIA/dllogger.git'
pip install 'openfold @ git+https://github.com/aqlaboratory/openfold.git@4b41059694619831a7db195b7e0988fc4ff3a307'
```

I am getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 34, in 
File "/private/var/folders/_t/p573f1js2w5dx_xvd_h112h40000gn/T/pip-install-642l7elx/openfold_c56845d2684b4f048f7707a25b36ac5a/setup.py", line 21, in 
from scripts.utils import get_nvidia_cc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.utils'

I tried to install `utilts` and `scripts.utils`, but it didnt work.

Comment: Seems like an issue with the Openfold repository - maybe open an issue there: https://github.com/aqlaboratory/openfold/issues

Comment: This one, it seems: https://github.com/aqlaboratory/openfold/issues/341